# Visibility of tree at startup

Tags: org-mode, visibility

I just came back to org-mode after ~10 years and I am (of course) getting lost even facing the minimal configuration issue :-)

I would like that when I open a `.org` file I see all the headers, regardless from their level. So, if my file is:

```
* Project A
** TODO task 1
** TODO task 2
   :LOGBOOK:
   - ...somethign goes here...
   :END:
*** TODO subtask 2.1
*** TODO subtast 2.2
    Here there is a lot of text
    A lot of notes
** TODO task2

* Project B
** This is not a task
   bla bla bla
** TODO Task B1

* TODO Random Task
* TODO Another Random Task
```

I would like to see:

```
* Project A
** TODO task 1
** TODO task 2...
*** TODO subtask 2.1
*** TODO subtast 2.2...
** TODO task2
* Project B
** This is not a task...
** TODO Task B1
* TODO Random Task
* TODO Another Random Task
```

How can I do? I would rather have a setting within my `init.el` than a in-buffer setting, but just in case, every solution is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```lisp
(setq org-startup-folded 'content)
```

to your `init.el` should do the trick.

See ['Initial visibility' in the Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!